# Setting a Timeout For a Flash Notice

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, flash

```
def destroy
@cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
session[:cart_id] = nil
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to store_url,
    notice: 'Your cart is currently empty' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end
```

I'm working my way through Agile Web Development with Rails 4 and throughout the book they're having you create a website with a cart. What I'm trying to do is make sure that the notice message that pops up when you empty your cart disappears after a few seconds. As it stands currently, the notice message stays on the screen until you refresh. What would I need to do to make sure this occurs? I've tried messing around with Javascript and creating a .js.erb file, however, I can't seem to get it just right.

Answer (score 2):

For this you'll need to use some javascript.

The most simple approach is to do the following:

**Step 1: Modify your flash messages output**

Open application.html or whenever you are rendering your flash messages, and wrap them inside a `<div id="flash-messages">` element.

For example, if you have this:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :class => "flash_#{name}" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Wrap them in this way:

```
<div id="flash-messages">
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, :class => "flash_#{name}" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Step 2: Remove flash messages with a little piece of Javascript**

Inside `assets/javascript/application.js`, add the following piece of code:

```
$(function(){
   var flashDurationInSeconds = 5;
   var flashContainerId = 'flash-messages';

   function removeFlashMessages() {
     $('#' + flashContainerId).remove();
   }

   setTimeout(removeFlashMessages, flashDurationInSeconds * 1000);
})
```

Update `flashDurationInSeconds` to whatever the duration you need and `flashContainerId` to the ID you added in the step 1.

**Done!**

This way, every flash message will lasts only for 5 seconds, as you wish.

Comment: What if for example it's not being rendered, but produced by the controller? Is that the same thing? Or would a different approach be necessary?

Comment: What do you mean by "not being rendered but produced by the controller"? In any case you will need to use JavaScript to hide the message.

Comment: This piece of code is in the controller for the cart portion of my Agile app. It's not being rendered by code put into the view. Later on they have you remove this, so when you're moving around there isn't an error message still popping up.